# Is there a way to view a list of comments in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I know how to make comments appear on the right side of the document. But is there a way to list down all comments made in the document so I see all of them at once instead of scrolling down the entire doc looking for them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two answers (with some overlap):

Step 1: On the “Review” tab, in the “Tracking” panel,
go into the “Show Markup” dropdown
and clear everything but “Comments”, like this:
        [image: “Show Markup” dropdown]
(If you don’t have any tracked changes (other than comments) you can skip this step.)

**and then either**

Step 2A: Still in the “Tracking” panel, enable a “Reviewing Pane”, like this:
        [image: “Reviewing Pane” dropdown]
… and you’ll get something like this:
                          [image: “Reviewing Pane” — list of tracked changes and comments in the document]

**or**

Step 2B: Print “List of markup”, like this:
        [image: Print dialog box — Print what]
Output is similar to what you get in the Reviewing Pane.

---

These instructions work,
with trivial changes in the appearance of the user interface, in Word 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This method may look cumbersome but it can be useful in certain situations:

If you save the document as .txt it will contain the main text of the document at first, and the comment list at the end, in this format:

```
[MG1]The whole table needs to be reviewed and updated.
[MG2]Remove section 2.2.4
[MG3]Insert correct reference.
...
```